# Removing blank lines between only certain other matching lines

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to remove blank lines between other lines that match a particular pattern.  In my case, that pattern is just that the line begins with a `-` character.

```
const orig = `
- line1

- line2

- line3

- line4

- line5
`.trim();

const actual =
  orig.replace(/((?:^|\n)-.*\n)\n(-)/g, '$1$2');
```

In the code above, I'm using a regex to match:

- a newline (or string start), followed by...
- a `-` prefixed line, followed by..
- an empty line, followed by...
- another `-`

I'm globally replacing the entire expression with the two capture groups that omit the empty line between them.  This *sort of* works like I expected it to, but omits every other empty line, and I don't know why.

Where I would have expected the code above to give me this:

```
- line1
- line2
- line3
- line4
- line5
```

...it actually gives me this:

```
- line1
- line2

- line3
- line4

- line5
```

[Here is a fiddle that demonstrates the problem.](https://jsfiddle.net/b2gs4j0t/3/)

**Question: What about the regex is causing this behavior?**

*Bonus: Is there a better way to do this? (e.g. via `split`/`reduce` - although I would still like to know why it doesn't work)*

Comment: You match `- line1`, the blank line, and `- line2` capturing the two lines with text; at that point you have _consumed_ line2 so it is not available to match again, meaning the next thing available for a match is `- line3` ... the blank line between lines 2 and 3 is not part of any match so is left alone. Be aware that `/g` global does not _re-scan_ the line; it continues from the last match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is that the regex does not overlap matches. It consumes and matches:

```
- line 1

-
```

Replaces with:

```
- line 1
-
```

And then continues traversing the string from the end of its previous match.

For this reason it does not match the next newline, because

```
  line 2

- line 3
```

Does not contain a match your pattern. The next match to your pattern will be

```
<newline>
- line 3

-
```

Replaced by:

```
<newline>
- line 3
-
```

A way to solve this is by using either [lookaheads or lookbehinds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-lookahead), which allow [conditional matching based on surrounding patterns without consuming those patterns](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html).

We can modify your pattern slightly to use a lookahead to make sure the next line adheres to the pattern

```
const actual = orig.replace(/^(-.*\n)\n(?=-)/gm, '$1');
```

https://regex101.com/r/fPUkYh/4

I also changed `((?:^|\n)-.*\n)\n` to `^(-.*\n)\n` and added the `m` flag because the start of line assertion `^` does not need to be in the capturing group and the `\n` leads to the removal of preceding newlines.

This pattern could also be modified to match an arbitrary number of bl;ank lines in between lines matching the pattern:

```
/^(-.*\n)\n+(?=-)/gm
```

https://regex101.com/r/X7B7pi/2

Answer (score 2):

The last `-` is a part of the consuming pattern. Once the `(-)` matches, the regex index is set after that `-`, and you cannot find that match as `-` in `(?:^|\n)-` cannot match that `-`.  You need to put it into a positive lookahead. Then, you need to use `m` modifier to let `^` match start of a *line* positions, not just start of string.

Use

```
/((?:^|\n)-.*\n)\n(?=-)/gm
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1lgZq3/3). Replacement string is reduced to `$1` since there is only one capturing group left.

Here is the fixed expression demo:

```js
const orig = `
- line1

- line2

- line3

- line4

- line5
`.trim();

const actual =
 orig.replace(/((?:^|\n)-.*\n)\n(?=-)/gm, '$1');

document.getElementById('orig').innerText = orig;
document.getElementById('actual').innerText = actual;
```

```css
ul { font-family: sans-serif; list-style: none; padding: 0; }
li { display: inline-block; padding: 1em; vertical-align: top; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><h3>Original</h3><pre id="orig"></pre></li>
  <li><h3>Expected</h3><pre>- line1<br />- line2<br />- line3<br />- line4<br />- line5</pre></li>
  <li><h3>Actual</h3><pre id="actual"></pre></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: hahaha, dangit Wiktor, you're ever so slightly faster than me!

Comment: @WillBarnwell: Yeah, but my solution is different.

Comment: Probably works better, I knew it was an answer race so i didn't test much

Comment: @WillBarnwell I just realized that won't work because of the `m` modifier and removed the comment.

Comment: Also removed my comments, in other sniping at other's regex work, yours compresses lines that don't have a separating newline https://regex101.com/r/c7BovY/3

Comment: @WillBarnwell OK, I see. The alternation must be put back into Group 1. Then, I am not sure what to do with the first empty line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153159/discussion-between-will-barnwell-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 1):

Easy enough when using the *Multi-line* modifier `//m`

```
 (                             # (1 start), Stuff to write back
      ^                             # BOL
      - .* 
      \r? \n      
 )                             # (1 end)
 \s*                           # Blank lines to remove
 \r? \n
```

```js
var orig_str = "- line1\n\n\n- line2\n\n- line3\n\n- line4\n\n- line5\n- line6";

var new_str =
 orig_str.replace(/(^-.*\r?\n)\s*\r?\n/mg, '$1');
  
  
console.log( "Original\n--------\n" +  orig_str + "\n" );
console.log( "New\n--------\n" +  new_str );
```

Output

```
Original
--------
- line1


- line2

- line3

- line4

- line5
- line6


New
--------
- line1
- line2
- line3
- line4
- line5
- line6
```

---

If just between `-lines` is what you need, just add an assertion at the
end [(^-.*\r?\n)\s*\r?\n(?=-)](https://regex101.com/r/c7BovY/4)

Comment: @WillBarnwell  - What does `compresses the trailing newline` mean to you ?

Comment: Sorry, `*removes`

Comment: @WillBarnwell  - You can think of it this way:  .. There are 2 squares, one for the line to be written back, one for the blank lines. Each square is terminated with a newline. Only 1 square is written back. Result is format is preserved.

Comment: I'm just pointing it out because OP said "between" not "after", if Op's desire was to eliminate newlines between the items and leave everything else perfectly alone, then your regex is not a perfect answer

Comment: @WillBarnwell  - I guess the hard part is to be smart enough to add an assertion on the end `(^-.*\r?\n)\s*\r?\n(?=-)`, but it's not Nobel Prize territory, nor would I ever read that much detail into a question. https://regex101.com/r/c7BovY/4

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the following way

```js
const orig = `
- line1

- line2

- line3

- line4

- line5
`.trim();

const actual =
 orig.replace(/(\-[^\n]*)([^-]*)(?=-)/g, '$1\n');

document.getElementById('orig').innerText = orig;
document.getElementById('actual').innerText = actual;
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><h3>Original</h3><pre id="orig"></pre></li>
  <li><h3>Expected</h3><pre>- line1<br />- line2<br />- line3<br />- line4<br />- line5</pre></li>
  <li><h3>Actual</h3><pre id="actual"></pre></li>
</ul>
```

see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aJC1fI/1)

Answer (score 0):

Here a shorter regex including your pattern to mach:

`const actual = orig.replace(/(-.*\n)\n/g, '$1');`

Answer (score -1):

This will give you what you need -

```
const actual = orig.replace(/\n\n|\r\r/g, "\n");
```

Comment: This doesn't ensure that the blank line is between certain lines

Comment: @WillBarnwell According to the question, blank lines are not needed between any lines

Comment: "remove blank lines between other lines that match a particular pattern"